# A Nice Simple Cipher

Tags: cipher

I assure you the following text is not gibberish, it is a real translation using a very simple cipher.

> Truffle Blue Umbrella Jump Turtle Granular Bird Dump Used Jammed Plates Orangatan.

Enjoy!

Comment: it's 'orangutan' you monkey!

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I see!!! the cypher is to substitute every 7th "a" into an "u"!!!

Comment: I remember a high-school English teacher, who had herself failed English at high school, reading a "listening comprehension" test passage. She carefully pronounced every "orangutan" as "orange-you-tan".

Answer (score 6):

Easy:

> Take the first letter of each letter, giving: `TBUJTGBDUJPO`

Then

> Apply a 1-shift Caesar cipher, giving: `SATISFACTION`

Comment: Nice and quick find! +1